# awk : lines in file.txt that match any of the strings in file

Tags: unix, awk

I have two separate .txt files:

list.txt, containing a list of strings:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

and entries.txt, containing different lines with 7 fields

```
name field2 field3 field4 field6 string1 field8
```

I need to get all lines from entries.txt whose 7th fields is == to ANY ONE of the lines in list.txt.

I know with grep, this is `grep -F list.txt entries.txt`, but I need it to be specifically in the 7th field, so I wanted to use awk.

So it would be something like `awk '$7==$(any string from list.txt)'`

How can I write the `$(any string from list.txt)` part?

Comment: With `grep` it’s actually `grep -Ff list.txt entries.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

try this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$7 in a' list.txt entries.txt
```

didn't test, but should work for your requirement.

**NOTE**  :  **$6 or $7** ?

you said in your question, it should be `$7`, so I used `$7`. but look at your example, it seems that it should be `$6` ? anyway, you could change the column index by yourself.